# Need help assigning variables to VBScript WMI array results

Tags: vbscript, wmi, sccm

I am trying to write a VBScript that pulls 3 different properties from the same WMI class (`Win32_DiskDrive`).  That class gives an array if you have more than one drive.  I want to assign all of the results from the array to SCCM variables, but having trouble doing that because I've never done something quite like this before.

Here is my script:

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20

Dim objWMIService, objItem, colItems, strComputer, Index, Model, Size
Dim Index(4)
Index(0) = Index0
Index(1) = Index1
Index(2) = Index2
Index(3) = Index3

Dim Model(4)
Model(0) = Model0
Model(1) = Model1
Model(2) = Model2
Model(3) = Model3

Dim Size(4)
Size(0) = Size0
Size(1) = Size1
Size(2) = Size2
Size(3) = Size3

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
Set env = CreateObject("Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment")

For Each objItem in colItems
    Index(4) = objItem.Index
    Model(4) = objItem.Model
    Size(4) = objItem.Size
    env("DriveIndex") = Index(4)
    env("DriveModel") = Model(4)
    env("DriveBytes") = Size(4)
Next
```

Comment: Is your question how to build distinct arrays from the properties of the WMI objects? Or is it how to assign values to SCCM variables?

Comment: You will need distinct variables for each drive OR you will need to concatenate your results in a string. The way you have it here, the last drive in the list is going to be assigned to the variables because the loop will cause the values to be overwritten "for each objItem." How you approach this really does depend on what you're looking to do with these values later on.

Comment: Ansgar, I know how to make SCCM variables in general, but I needed to know how to get the correct values from WMI so I could assign them as variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution that doesn't need arrays in your vbscript. It will output a TS variable that has a suffix of the drive number (starting at 0, or whatever you set `iCount` to start).

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20

Dim objWMIService, objItem, colItems, strComputer
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
Set env = CreateObject("Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment")

iCount = 0
For Each objItem in colItems
    env("DriveIndex" & iCount) = objItem.Index
    env("DriveModel" & iCount) = objItem.Model
    env("DriveBytes" & iCount) = objItem.Size
    iCount = iCount + 1
Next
```

So if you have 3 drives you'll end up with something like this in SCCM:
`DriveIndex0 = TheIndexOf0`
`DriveModel0 = TheModelOf0`
`DriveSize0 = TheSizeOf0`
`DriveIndex1 = TheIndexOf1`
`DriveModel1 = TheModelOf1`
`DriveSize1 = TheSizeOf1`
`DriveIndex2 = TheIndexOf2`
`DriveModel2 = TheModelOf2`
`DriveSize2 = TheSizeOf2`

You could then reference each variable later in the TS the same way you normally would. `%DriveIndex0%`,`%DriveIndex1%`, etc.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for.  I will test it out and mark as the answer if it worked.  Thanks!